# ExoPlayer not working for some streams

Tags: android, stream, audio-streaming, exoplayer

I have this type of stream: http://radiohoryzont.jgora.pl:8050. 
The problem is, that when I try to play it using ExoPlayer, following exception is thrown.

> E/ExoPlayerImplInternal: Internal track renderer error.
>                                                                                       com.google.android.exoplayer.ExoPlaybackException:
>   com.google.android.exoplayer.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException:
>   Unable to connect to http://radiohoryzont.jgora.pl:8050

Strange thing is, that on another mobile phone it seems to be working (it is working on Android 6, but not on Android 4). Could somebody help me with this?

I am using EMAudioPlayer.

```
 mediaPlayer = new EMAudioPlayer(getApplicationContext());
 mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
 mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(), myURI);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try replacing the `http://` with `icy://` in your link. This is according to ExoPlayer Issue's page on [**Github**](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1003). Anyways your radio link is giving MP3 audio (44.1khz, 128k, stereo, etc) so there's no reason for Android 4 devices NOT to be able to play the audio part.

Comment: Also worth a shot (untested)... Make a basic MP3 playback code but instead of some storage MP3 URI use `http://radiohoryzont.jgora.pl:8050/;` (note the semi colon added at URL ending). Also try this with normal Android SDK (eg: `MediaPlayer` API) code as used for usual MP3 playback... Good luck.

Comment: @VC.One replacement to icy:// is not working.

Comment: @VC.One I tried http://stream.tvojeradio.com:8500/;stream/1 as well (this is used by other players), still not working.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been solving the very same issue recently and found the solution.

The URL which fails for you is a ShoutCast and these are not working well with `HttpDataSource` on Android 4. However if you manage to replace this with `OkHttpDataSource`, data will be retrieved correctly.

You are using `EMAudioPlayer`, which uses `ExoPlayer` to stream music (for API level 16+). You can easily replace `HttpDataSource` with `OkHttpDataSource`:

```
    TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(
        new Handler(),
        new AdaptiveVideoTrackSelection.Factory(
            new DefaultBandwidthMeter()
        )
    );
    mediaPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
        getApplicationContext(),
        trackSelector,
        new DefaultLoadControl()
    );
    MediaSource source = new ExtractorMediaSource(
        myURI,
        new OkHttpDataSourceFactory(
            new OkHttpClient(),
            userAgent,
            null
        ),
        new DefaultExtractorsFactory(),
        null,
        null
    );
    mediaPlayer.prepare(source);
    mediaPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```